# How to move single element of XML into Another Element using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to move the element `id` to `Here` My Input xml is

```
<COLLECTION>
<abc>
<id>1234</id>
</abc>

        <AddedParts NAME="AddedParts" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
            <Part>
            </Part>
            <Here>
            </Here>
        </AddedParts>
</COLLECTION>
```

Expected output is

```
<COLLECTION>
<abc>

</abc>

        <AddedParts NAME="AddedParts" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
            <Part>
            </Part>
            <Here>
            <id>1234</id>
            </Here>
        </AddedParts>
</COLLECTION>
```

The xsl i write is

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output method= "xml" version= "1.0" encoding= "UTF-8" indent= "yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements= "*" />

     <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

        <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
          <xsl:copy>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
          </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>



        <xsl:template match= "Here" >
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select= "node()|@*" />
            <!-- move nodes to here -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select= "../id " mode= "move" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template >
< xsl:template match= "id" />
```

I am unable to achieve the expected output

Comment: this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665616/move-an-xml-element-into-another-element-with-xslt) might help you.

Comment: @greenPadawan Thanks for reply but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You've got two things wrong with your current XSLT

1. You are trying to select `../id`, but `id` is not a child of the current parent, but a child of the `abc` element under the current grand-parent. It should be `../../abc/id`.
2. You are applying a template with a mode of "move" but have no matching template with that mode, meaning XSLT's built-in templates will be used, which would output the text content of `id`, but not the element itself.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output method= "xml" version= "1.0" encoding= "UTF-8" indent= "yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements= "*" />

     <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

        <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
          <xsl:copy>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
          </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="Here" >
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select= "node()|@*" />
            <!-- move nodes to here -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select= "../../abc/id" mode="move" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match= "id" />

    <xsl:template match="id" mode="move">
        <xsl:call-template name="identity" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you don't intend to try to transform `id` in any way, you could simplify it to this...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output method= "xml" version= "1.0" encoding= "UTF-8" indent= "yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements= "*" />

     <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

        <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
          <xsl:copy>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
          </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="Here" >
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select= "node()|@*" />
            <!-- move nodes to here -->
            <xsl:copy-of select= "../../abc/id"  />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match= "id" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Is is possible to convert kg into lbs using xslt let say `<main>
<part>
<weight>1</weight>
<weightunits></weightunits>
</part>
</main>` is my xml and i want to convert `<weight>` value to LBS and put the output into `<weightunits>`

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You would have a template matching `weightunits` and in that do the conversion in that. If you can't work it out, it really warrants a whole new question here on SO. It's perfectly fine to add a separate follow-up question. Thanks

Comment: Also note, I have amended my answer as I had previously said there was no "Here" element in your XSLT, when then clearly was! Sorry!